# Convert Openni code to Openini2 API

Tags: visual-c++, openni

I have a code in openni 1, and i want to "convert" it to openni2 api.
I have this types:

```
xn::Context        m_Context;
xn::DepthGenerator m_Depth;
xn::ImageGenerator m_RGBGen;
```

There an similar class at Openini2?

Thanks for the help,
Tal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a similar class in Openni2

if you check the migration guide [here](http://com.occipital.openni.s3.amazonaws.com/OpenNI_Migration_Guide_1_to_2.pdf)

you can see that `xn::DepthGenerator` and `xn::ImageGenerator` are replaced by the `openni::VideoStream` class. And the `openni::OpenNI` class replaces the `xn::Context`.

The change between both openni is huge, and it will require more than just changing the class of the variables, though it is not a hard task. If you have any question just comment the answer.

Comment: How i convert RGB888Pixel to RGB byte-stream array?

Comment: @Tal You can always use 'reinterpret_cast' and take it as a uchar array, or create a cv::Mat of type 8UC3 if you use opencv and copy the buffer to the cv::Mat.data. https://github.com/cvlabbonn/tools_openni2 here you have an example of openni2